# Zooming while clusters render causes map to freeze

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, ionic-framework, markerclusterer

I am using the gmaps-marker-clusterer library (v1.2.0) together with the Google Maps API on an Ionic v1 app to group map markers in clusters based on the zoom level.

I am currently stuck on one particular issue caused by the library (it does not happen when I am not using it) that somehow makes the map freeze on a weird one-finger zoom mode. Essentially, when zooming in or out while the clusters are rendering, the map gets stuck, does not load anymore and instead of rendering new map textures when the user tries to move the centre of the map it just zooms in or out (but without rendering or loading). No error message is being displayed.

All markers (40/50) are loaded together, only once, when the map initialises. This only happens on an actual iPhone device. I have not tested it on Android, but I can say this is not happening while testing the app in the browser. See a screenshot of the frozen map [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sxA8.jpg).

Has anyone come across anything similar? Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: any progress on this? thanks

Comment: No progress, unfortunately. In the end we decided not to use the gmaps-marker-clusterer library at all. We also switched to the [Cordova GoogleMaps plugin](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps) for the map functionality. Are you experiencing a similar issue?

Comment: yes - opened issue here: https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/issues/374

Comment: Same problem here with custom overlay. When overlay isn’t completely rendered and you start zooming, the map freezes. Any update?

Answer (score 0):

Try to load only the markers within  the view